# Is REXX available in .NET?

Tags: .net, dynamic-language-runtime, rexx

Is anyone aware of a REXX implementation for .NET? Or plans for one, perhaps using the DLR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm...the answer appears to be "No"