# Are there any implementation of REXX PARSE written for .NET?

Tags: .net, parsing, rexx, snobol

I use regular expressions all the time. However, there are occasions when it would be very helpful to be able to use one of the other pattern matching methodologies, for example, REXX PARSE and SNOBOL.

Are there any .NET implementations of either of these two pattern matching methods? If [is-rexx-available-in-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002586/is-rexx-available-in-net) is anything to go by, the likelihood isn't high. Google isn't being very friendly at the moment, giving me way too many links to RosettaCode.

Comment: Not that I know of. This http://ibm-netrexx.215625.n3.nabble.com/NetRexx-Net-td4025198.html is a discussion netrexx for .net; Jason Martin said he has a c# version of the net-rexx library (which I presume holds parse code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **YES**. I found some old VB6 code from a programmer called Oscar Brain. I've converted it to VB.Net and then to C#. It's on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/axtens/rexxparse-in-c). It's not perfect, but there's an [updated VB6 version on Planet Source Code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=53225&lngWId=1) which I will port over when time permits.

Answer (score 1):

F# has something called "Active patterns" which might do what you want. Look here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-active-patterns/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **NO**. As of now there is no implementation for REXX PARSE written for .NET